# Excel radian or degrees?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I’m not sure whether excel requires inputs into cos() in Degrees or Radians please?

For example: for cos(x) where x=1,2,… degrees, should I convert to radians first please or?

Comment: Have you read the doc?

Comment: Have you tried testing with known values?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cos-function-0fb808a5-95d6-4553-8148-22aebdce5f05

Comment: why don't just read the official documentation? Anyway trigonometric functions are almost always in radian because degrees are pretty much useless in math

Comment: `=SIN(PI()/2)` => 1

Comment: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-cos-function

Answer (score 0):

It requires radians.

You can convert from your degrees entry to radians inside the function's parentheses:

```
=SIN(A1  *PI()/180  )
```

being an example.

So enter, or otherwise source your angle measurements however you like or find convenient (or necessary).

Just be sure which measure you are using and convert if not radians.

When `phuclv` says degrees are pretty much useless in math, it is in the same way that having a number entered/stored/generated as text is in Excel:  perfectly fine if you wish to go to more effort than you really have to, and may be valuable for the reader/user or yourself. BUT... `not directly ("naturally") useable` is a pretty inconvenient aspect that most cases experience very, very soon. And don't like. Degrees in math may be more understandable to you, the user, but not to most uses past today's homework. So maybe valuable, or maybe today is a good day to start trying to get used to radian measures enough for them to feel as natural as degrees do now... in a few years.

I ain't nev-ah gonna. Just too, too old to care. I'll convert in my head for visualization and such (long as I can anyway...) but even that said, I don't fight it in Excel, or most other places. Been trying on and off for 40 years now, so if you decide to work on that, don't be bummed out if it takes a bit of time.